# Postgres Full Text Search - Find Other Similar Documents

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I am looking for a way to use Postgres (version 9.6+) Full Text Search to find other documents similar to an input document - essentially looking for a way to produce similar results to [Elasticsearch's more_like_this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) query. Far as I can tell Postgres offers no way to compare `ts_vectors` to each other.

I've tried various techniques like converting the source document back into a `ts_query`, or reprocessing the original doc but that requires too much overhead.

Would greatly appreciate any advice - thanks!

Comment: I agree: a function for obtaining some distance metric between two ts_vectors would indeed be a nice feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the only option is to use `pg_trgm` instead of the Postgres built in full text search. Here is how I ended up implementing this:

Using a simple table (or materialized view in this case) - it holds the primary key to the post and the full text body in two columns.

```
Materialized view "public.text_index"
Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
id     | integer |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
post   | text    |           |          |         | extended |              | 

View definition:
SELECT posts.id,
posts.body AS text
FROM posts
ORDER BY posts.publication_date DESC;
```

Then using a lateral join we can match rows and order them by [similarity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/pgtrgm.html) to find posts that are "close to" or "related" to any other post:

```
select * from text_index tx 
left join lateral (
  select similarity(tx.text, t.text) from text_index t where t.id = 12345
) s on true 
order by similarity 
desc limit 10;
```

This of course is a naive way to match documents and may require further tuning. Additionally using a tgrm gin index on the text column will speed up the searches significantly.